# Undefined variable when declaring with concatenation

Tags: php, string, concatenation, undefined

I get an undefined variable $ar, $pr and $af.

```
$sql = mysqli_query($connection, "Select empno, username, password, access_level from personaltab where access_level='ADMIN'");

$cnt = mysqli_num_rows($sql);
$i=0;

while ($r=mysqli_fetch_array($sql)){
$md = md5($r['username']."!@#$%^&*()_+|");
$ar .= $md.", ";
$mdp = md5($r['password']."|+_)(*&^%$#@!<>?:{}[]=-");
$pr .= $mdp.", ";
$af .= $r['empno'].", ";
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to initialize the variables before the loop. Otherwise, there's no initial value to concatenate to.

```
$ar = '';
$pr = '';
$af = '';
while ($r = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)) {
    ...
}
```